# Replace Multidimensional Array values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a multidimensional array and i want to replace the `timestamp` field in it..

```
Array
(
    [new_messages] => 0
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42
            [sender] => 4
            [receiver] => 4
            [message] => Test
            [timestamp] => 1368178683
            [read] => 1
            [s_deleted] => 0
            [r_deleted] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [sender] => 4
            [receiver] => 4
            [message] => test2
            [timestamp] => 1368181485
            [read] => 1
            [s_deleted] => 0
            [r_deleted] => 0
        )
)
```

---

I run:

```
foreach ($messageArray as $key => $row) {
   $orderByDate[$key]  = $row['timestamp'];
   $newTimestamp = date("d-M-Y H:i:s", $row['timestamp']);
   $messageArray[$key]['timestamp'] = $newTimestamp;
}
```

It does work, replaces it, but i get a Warning:

> **Warning**: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Why? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some of your root array elements are not arrays, like:

```
[new_messages] => 0
```

So there's no `timestamp` key to access. Just add:

```
if(!is_array($row))
  continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

It also wants to change the timestamp of the key `new_messages`, but there isn't one (it's just a single value).

Change to this

```
foreach ($messageArray as $key => $row) {
   if (!is_array($row) || !array_key_exists('timestamp', $row)) {
     continue;
   }
   $orderByDate[$key]  = $row['timestamp'];
   $newTimestamp = date("d-M-Y H:i:s", $row['timestamp']);
   $messageArray[$key]['timestamp'] = $newTimestamp;
}
```